# How to get UDP or TCP logs from a docker container using NLog

Tags: docker, nlog

How can I configure docker and Nlog to have tcp logging? I use log4view and udp logging works smoothly on my machine with the following config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Debug"
      internalLogFile="c:\Temp\internal-nlog.txt">


  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="c:\Temp\xRayServices-${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

    <target name="udp" xsi:type="Network" address="udp4://localhost:9999"
            layout="${log4jxmlevent}" newline="True" />
  </targets>
    <target name="tcp" xsi:type="Network" address="tcp4://localhost:9995"
            layout="${log4jxmlevent}" newline="True" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,udp,tcp" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I also use the file target in the above config  to write logs in the docker container to a file and then I map the docker directory to my system directory when starting the docker image as follows (simplified to keep only the essentials):

```
docker run --rm --name myName  -p 9995:9995 -p 9999:9999/udp --network myLocalNet --mount "type=bind,source=C:\Temp,destination=C:\Temp" myImage
```

This works and I get usable txt file logs.  I would really like to use Log4view.

In my case I need to use --network myLocalNet for security reasons.

Is it possible to have tcp (or udp ) logging while using --network myLocalNet.

Note that in the above command I tried mapping the port 9999, but I do not receive the udp  logs (I am guessing because of the   --network myLocalNet).  In the logging config and the docker config,  I somehow need to make my computer IP adress visible to the docker container since logs are sent from the container to my computer.

**UPDATE**:  following feedback from @LinPy  I added the /udp flag,  I also mapped a seaparate tcp port  and updated the logging config.   The config works locally for tcp and udp  but still not from the container.

I also added EXPOSE 9999/udp and EXPOSE 9995 to the docker file

Answer (score 1):

try to publich both `TCP` and `UDP`:

```
docker run --rm --name myName -p 9999:9999/udp -p 9999:9999 --network myLocalNet --mount "type=bind,source=C:\Temp,destination=C:\Temp" myImage
```

Comment: but what should I use as the IP adress as the docker container? How can I obtain it?

Comment: you need to use `localhost` since you publich the ports, or the host `IP`

Comment: note that you can also `EXPOSE 9999/udp` in `Dockerfile`

Comment: thanks for the pointers,  which are indeed correct,  however I have updated my question and it is still not working.

Comment: still can not get both udp and tcp ?

Comment: cannot get neither udp nor tcp.  is this somehow related to the visibility of the network due to --network myLocalNet?

Comment: I do not think so, is there anything listen to port 9999 and 9995 in the container ? telnet to localhost 9999 works ?

Comment: note also that I assumed that the traffic get from outside the contianer to the container. if that not the case then yes you need to use the container IP, get it `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199951/discussion-between-shev72-and-linpy).

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to open any port with EXPOSE or specify the -p parameter to do a port mapping, since it is not an incoming connection, NLog does NOT open a port. NLog connects to the endpoint you define.

Therefore to make it work you just have to change `localhost:9999` to `<your-ip-host>:9999`